# How to tell the difference between interval and coordinate notation from context?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, real-numbers

I am working on a practice problem with sets. (the answer key)

[image]

At first I was confused by the notation Ai = (0,i), i is a natural number.
I looked up the use of paranthesis and saw that they could be used for coordinates and for open intervals). http://sites.csn.edu/istewart/mathweb/Math126/A_PREREQUISITES/p_notation_rounding/solution_notation.html

-"Sometimes certain Interval Notation and coordinates of a point look the same, which can be confusing.  However, in context you should be able to tell whether you are looking at Interval Notation or the coordinates of a point.
For example, in Interval Notation, (2, 6) would indicate an interval along the x-axis between 2 and 6, but not including 2 and 6.  As coordinates, (2, 6) would indicate the location of a point in the Cartesian Coordinate System with x-coordinate 2 and y-coordinate 6."

Is there a reason mathematicians chose to represent two different concepts with the same symbol? The link said to use the context of the problem to determine whether the values inside parenthesis represent a coordinate point or an open interval but in this example, I feel like this problem could work with both intervals, like you could have a union of a set of coordinate points or intervals. (I know its open interval because of the answer) But in general, how would you be able to tell?

Comment: In general it is impossible to tell, but that is what is meant by "in context" it is not in general it is in the context of a specific question.

Comment: Thats why I was unsure in terms of this problem as well. You could technically have a union of a bunch of coordinates.

Comment: It is possible, but the author would have to know that and make their meaning clear.

Comment: Also, technically the intersection of a collection of sets of coordinate points should be written as, for example, {(0,1)} and not (0,1).

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that there is a limited set of delimiter symbol and these symbols are reused in many different contexts. $\langle\,\rangle, (\,), [\,], \{\,\}$

Thus context is required to distinguish between the representations for things such as the open interval, $(a, b)$, and the coordinate point, $(a, b)$.

The key to context in this case is the *set operators*.

Expressions like $\,x\in (a, b)\,$, $\,(a, b)\cup(c, d)\,$, or $\,\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^n (a, k)\,$ clearly indicate that the bracketed entity is being treated as some form of set rather than a distinct point.

.

---

*Note:* Angle brackets are *sometimes* preferred for coordinates, and other ordered lists. $\langle a, b \rangle$

In $\LaTeX$: `\langle a, b \rangle`